# SQL Query with two Tables / difficult

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in which the regular working hours of employees are recorded. This is done on the one hand via the avaible_week table and on the other hand via the avaible_daily table.
In the week table the weekly standard working hours of the employees are recorded. If someone is on vacation or sick, this appears in the daily table.

Whether someone is available is recorded in the status
0=Not available
1=Available

Now we want to display in a SQL query which employees are available on a certain day.

With
`SELECT short FROM avaible_week WHERE day=1 AND hour =8`.

I get the abbreviations which are available at this time. But how do I link the output with the other table, in which someone is not available?

```
Week Table:
|id|short|day|time|state|
|1 |XY   |1  |8   |1    |

Day Table:
|id|short|day       |time|state|
|1 |XY   |09-04-2022|8   |0    |
```

Notice:
I still have tables with the names and times, but I can implement the EQUI-JOIN myself later.

Comment: How do you count days?  Which day of the week is the day that equals to `1` ?

Comment: When you know how to do an EQUI-JOIN, what is your problem with this join? (Beside the fact that it seems easier to ask, than to learn how to do it yourself?)

Comment: I am not clear what the week table represents - does it contain7 days per employee or 52 weeks with day running from 1 - 7?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to try this approach with necessary fixes:

```
SELECT short FROM available_week WHERE (day=1 AND hour =8) 
NOT IN (SELECT short FROM available_day WHERE state=0 AND day='2022-04-09') ;
```

This should first select all from available_week, then remove the ones which have state=0 in available_day.

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched exactly for this "NOT IN" Statement.